# Why does the CDF of a k-th order statistic have an ${n \choose i }$ term?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

The CDF of the k-th order statistic is given by-
\begin{align*}
 F_{X_{(k)}}(x) & = \sum_{i=k}^n {n \choose i} [F_X(x)]^i\cdot [1 - F_X(x)]^{n-i}
\end{align*}

But I do not understand why there is an ${ n \choose i}$ term there? From what I understand, there cannot be different combinations as we require the **first** (not *any*) $r$ many order-statistics to be $\leq x$. Say, if I wanted to calculate $F_{X_{(n-1)}}(x)$ , then I could do the following-
\begin{align*}
F_{X_{(n-1)}}(x) &=  P[X_{{(n-1)}} \leq x]
\\ &=  P[X_{{(n-1)}} \leq x < X_{(n)}] +  P[X_{{(n)}} \leq x ]
\\ &= [F_X(x)]^{n-1}\cdot[1 - F_X(x)] + [F_X(x)]^n
\\ &= [F_X(x)]^{n-1}
\end{align*}
But if I use the formula written above, the answer comes out to be-
\begin{align*}
F_{X_{(n-1)}}(x) &=  n[F_X(x)]^{n-1}\cdot[1 - F_X(x)] + [F_X(x)]^n
\end{align*}
It isn't clear to me why do we need the extra $(n-1)$ terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n=4$. Then $P(X_{(3)} \le x < X_{(4)})$ does **not** equal $[F_X(x)]^{3} (1-F_X(x))$. What is true is that
\begin{align}
P(X_1 \le x, X_2 \le x, X_3 \le x, X_4 > x)
\\
P(X_1 \le x, X_2 \le x, X_3 > x, X_4 \le x)
\\
P(X_1 \le x, X_2 > x, X_3 \le x, X_4 \le x)
\\
P(X_1 > x, X_2 \le x, X_3 \le x, X_4 \le x)
\end{align}
each have probability $[F_X(x)]^3 (1-F_X(x))$ (note that we have crucially used independence of $X_1,\ldots, X_4$, whereas $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(4)}$ are not independent, nor are their CDFs the same as $F_X$).
Summing the four probabilities above yields $4[F_X(x)]^3(1-F_X(x))$.

Comment: This clarifies my doubt, I wasn't thinking of the samples. Thank you!